# Suppose $f \in B_{d_1}(g,\epsilon)$ can we conclude that $f \in B_{d_2}(g,\epsilon)$

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $f \in B_{d_1}(g,\epsilon)$ can we conclude that $f \in B_{d_2}(g,\epsilon)$

where the space is $C[0,1]$ and $d_1$ is the metric induced by the $1$ norm and $d_2$ is the metric induced by the $2$ norm

I feel it is true but cant prove it.What about converse?Any hints

Comment: No. Take $g=0$. For $n$ a positive integer, the function $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ satisfies $B_{d_1}(f_n,0)=1$ and   $B_{d_2}(f_n,0)=\sqrt n$. It's not hard to find a "continuous version" of these functions.

Comment: will the converse hold @DavidMitra

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz, $\Vert f\Vert_{L_1} \le \Vert f\Vert_{L_2}\cdot\Vert 1_{[0,1]}\Vert_{L_2} =\Vert f\Vert_{L_2}\cdot 1$.

Comment: sorry but how can we vary the norm in LHS and RHS sorry if I sound silly

Comment: Please give some answer I am looking forward to you @DavidMitra

Comment: If $f\in B_{d_2}(g,\epsilon)$, then $\Vert f-g\Vert_{L_2}<\epsilon$. By the inequality, we have $f\in B_{L_1}(g,\epsilon)$. Is this what you want? I'm not sure what your last comment means.

Comment: in LHS you have $L_1$ and in RHS $L_2$ how? the norm should be same; is not it?

Comment: No. Generally $\Vert f\Vert_{L_1} =\int_0^1 |f|\ne\Vert f\Vert_{L_2}=\Bigl(\int_0^1|f|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}$.